# Python: count it int but python thinks it is str

Tags: python, string, count, int

I checked the "python" count function and found it to be integer, but when I try to check if it is greater than a certain number, it shows me that it is str

```
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0

for i in words:
    i = str(i)
    if (words.count(i) > one):
        one = i

    elif (words.count(i) > two):
        two = i

    elif (words.count(i) > three):
        three = i
```

The Error:

```
    if (words.count(i) > one):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: it seems like 'one' is a string. How is it defined?

Comment: Since you don't show how `one` gets its initial value we can't see what's wrong.  But if Python says it's a string, then you can be sure it's a string.

Comment: `not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` That error message is more helpful than you realize -- it's telling you that the int is on the left and the str is on the right.  i.e. `one` is a str.

Comment: Both variables are int

Comment: what are `words`?

Comment: No they are not.  `one` is a string.  (Remember, when you print a string, the quotes are _not_ shown, so it can _look_ like an integer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
i = str(i)
```

So later, when you assign a new value to `one`:

```
one = i
```

`one` becomes a string.  Instead of changing `i`, change the `if`:

```
if (words.count(str(i)) > one):
```